# Using manifest data in resource file

Tags: android, android-manifest, resource-files

I would like to create a TextView which displays current application version.

Is it possible to use manifest data (in this case `versionName` attribute) in XML resource file to achieve this?

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"

    android:text = "(VERSION NAME)"
/>
```

Comment: it is possible only programatically

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the build/version number of your Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616095/how-to-get-the-build-version-number-of-your-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested but try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18701942/1979882):

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="?android:attr/versionName"
     />
    <!-- or -->
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="?android:attr/versionCode"
     />
```

If it doesnt the only solution is to use it [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13790076/1979882)

```
context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
```

or [use data from strings.xml in AndroidMainfest.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9722986/1979882).

Comment: Read that topic. I think no more solutions to do it in resources.