# Android: "update version 0 is older than installed version"

Tags: android

I'm building an Android app in release mode. The first time I install it on a device, it works fine. But if I rebuild it from the same source, sign it with the same key, and reinstall, it fails. I get the following error in the logs:

```
W/InstallAppProgress(30456): Replacing package:com.mycompany.myapp
W/ActivityManager(26370): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/MyApp-17.apk
W/PackageManager(26370): Can't install update of com.mycompany.myapp update version 0 is older than installed version 3
```

The version code of the app is set to 3, both times I build it. Where is it getting the idea that the update is "version 0"?

**UPDATE:** I have this in my manifest file: `android:versionCode="@integer/app_version_code"`. And I have `<integer name="app_version_code">3</integer>` defined in `res/values/strings.xml`.

I'm pretty sure this used to work, but now it doesn't seem to. If I replace the @integer reference with a hard-coded "3", it works. Shouldn't @integer [be supported](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer)?

Comment: can you post your manifest?

Comment: are you sure the Manifest is declaring the proper versionCode?

Comment: Updated the post, after checking the manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, **no**, you can't do that.

[See this Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/1dt0yxyNPsk), and [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6018079/119114) for some ideas for achieving a similar outcome with ant build scripting.

If you look at the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html), it specifically calls out that you **can** use a resource for the `versionName`, but says no such thing for the `versionCode`:

> `android:versionCode`
>
> An internal version number. This number is used only to determine
>   whether one version is more recent than another, with higher numbers
>   indicating more recent versions. This is not the version number shown
>   to users; that number is set by the versionName attribute.
>
> The value must be set as an integer, such as "100". You can define it
>   however you want, as long as each successive version has a higher
>   number. For example, it could be a build number. Or you could
>   translate a version number in "x.y" format to an integer by encoding
>   the "x" and "y" separately in the lower and upper 16 bits. Or you
>   could simply increase the number by one each time a new version is
>   released.
>
> `android:versionName`
>
> The version number shown to users. **This attribute can be set as a raw
>   string or as a reference to a string resource**. The string has no other
>   purpose than to be displayed to users. The versionCode attribute holds
>   the significant version number used internally.